# Windows .Bat File time stamp

Tags: batch-file

We have a Bat file that is renaming a file and placing a time stamp on it.  From 12:00am to 9:00am this time stamp is failing and I am not sure why

```
ren TheGMPRpt.csv TheGMPRpt_%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes because your time format has a leading space from midnight to 9am.

```
ren TheGMPRpt.csv "TheGMPRpt_%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.csv"
```

Comment: You can also remove the space, but a better solution is to use `WMIC` to derive a robust date/time stamp because the `date` variable is also dependent on regional settings in a computer so can change on any different machine, breaking your code.

Comment: That is a good idea.  However the process this answer helped fix is "good enough" to last the rest of the year till it gets retired in favor of a new platform my end users are moving to.  IF that doesn't happen I may circle back and use your suggestion to make this more robust.